# Split scatterplot data by categorical variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, categories

I have a dataset with three features: `Gender` ,`Weight` and `Height`. The `Gender` feature consists of Male and Female labels.

I'd like to create a graph that separates the data by color, based on `Gender`. The [pyplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) seems to indicate that some sort of numbering system is necessary for the `color` argument, so I was forced to separate like so:

```
male = dflog[dflog['Gender'] == 'Male']
female = dflog[dflog['Gender'] == 'Female']
_ = plt.scatter(male['Weight'], male['Height'], color='blue', marker='.', alpha=0.05)
_ = plt.scatter(female['Weight'], female['Height'], color='red', marker='.', alpha=0.05)
```

This is not ideal, for two reasons: One, it overcomplicates the situation--what could otherwise be done in one line of code is now done in four; and two, it overlays the gender data, rather than interpolates. I was forced to add the `alpha` just to see how far the Male data extends:
[image: scatterplot]

Is there any way to create this plot using a single line of `plt` code (or `sns`, I'm not particular)?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(male['Weight'], male['Height'], hue=male['Gender'])
plt.show()
```

If you have the same problem, maybe you should try facet (let me know if you need help with that)